# How to Perform Search in Ext JS Search Field

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have a search text field in my web page on which i want to trigger search upon entering a value in the text field.

[image]

I am using below snippet to put value in the Search textbox

var comp = Ext.getCmp('AccountNumber');
comp.setValue('2048007162');

Once the value is set i want trigger the search.

Comment: your "searchfield" should use `store` component to perform search by input value. Show your `store` definition and `AccountNumber` component definition

Answer (score 1):

```
On searchbox change event you have to load the store with search query 
Example
{
xtype: 'textfield',
text: 'Search',
emptyText: 'Search',
listeners: {
     'change' : function(field, value, oldvalue, eOpts) {
          this.store.load({params:{id: 1,search: value}});
     },
     scope:this,
}
```

You have to get the parameter search in the back end and according to that you have to write your query.